# RecyclerView populates too much data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I currently has a recyclerView that pulls in data from my firebase database. The recyclerview overpopulates by putting in items I do not have to fill up the list. I have already tried changing the layout_height from match parent to wrap content. This just made all my data disappear. I am just trying to accurately fill up the recyclerView with the accurate data from my firebase. Here is the code for the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FCF9F9"
    tools:context=".RecentReviews">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:background="#62BEE5">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroun_pattern_small_" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button"
            android:id="@+id/backButtonHistory"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/radomir_tinkov_gilroy_regular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backButtonHistory"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"/>

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="History"
            android:fontFamily="@font/radomir_tinkov_gilroy_regular"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image_uploadHistoy"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        app:civ_border_color="#696969"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Cole Stradtmann"
        android:fontFamily="@font/radomir_tinkov_gilroy_black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/txtDriverNameHist"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_uploadHistoy"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/job_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDriverNameHist"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10ssp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java:

```
package com.example.usub;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.usub.Model.History;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class RecentReviews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView jobList;
    private DatabaseReference jobRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserId;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recent_reviews);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        jobRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RateDetails").child(currentUserId);
       
        jobList = findViewById(R.id.job_list);
        jobList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        jobList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        DisplayAllJobs();
    }

    private void DisplayAllJobs() {

      //Query query = jobRef.orderByChild("comments"); // haven't implemented a proper list sort yet.

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<History> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<History>().setQuery(jobRef, History.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<History, jobsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final jobsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, int position, @NonNull History friends) {

                //friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());
                final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();

                jobRef.child(usersIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                           final String rateScore = dataSnapshot.child("rates").getValue().toString();
                           final String comment = dataSnapshot.child("comments").getValue().toString();
                           
                           jobsViewHolder.setRate(rateScore);
                           jobsViewHolder.setComments(comment);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            public jobsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.allratedisplay, parent ,false);
                return new jobsViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        jobList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public static class jobsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        static View mView;

        public jobsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public static void setRate(String rateScore) {
            TextView myName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.scoreRate);
            myName.setText(rateScore);
        }
        public static void setComments(String comment) {
            TextView myName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.scoreComment);
            myName.setText(comment);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `app:layout_behavior` on your `RecyclerView` as follow -

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/job_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDriverNameHist"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10ssp"/>
```

Then your recycle view will show even with `layout_height="wrap_content"`. You can also make `NestedScrollView` as parent of `RecycleView` but that will not be a good code practice.

---

**Additional Tip**

If you are going to use LinearLayout with RecycleView, it's a good option to put `LayoutManager` in xml itself as -

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ............
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

You can set `LinearLayoutManager(default orientation="vertical")`, `GridLayout` or `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

Happy Coding !